# How to merge two static libraries into single shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, linker

As part of my learning, I am trying to merge two static libraries into single shared library. Following sequence of commands I am using to prepare static libraries

> $gcc -c mathutil.cpp -o mathutil.o
>
> $ar rcs libmathutil.a mathutil.o
>
> $gcc -c dateutil.cpp -o dateutil.o
>
> $ar rcs libdateutil.a dateutil.o

Could somebody please tell me how to merge these two static libraries into single shared library.

I have tried the following command

> gcc -Wl,--whole-archive -shared libutil.so libmathutil.a

But it is giving lot of multiple definition errors.

Comment: If only sommebody had invented a convenient tool for sharing some of those errors. If only...

Comment: Perhaps you meant to type `-o libutil.so libmathutil.a libdateutil.a`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source files why not compile them into a shared library directly? Add the `-fPIC` flag to your compile lines (PIC = Position Independant Code), and then link something like:

Compile the files:

```
gcc -c -fPIC mathutil.cpp -o mathutil.o
gcc -c -fPIC dateutil.cpp -o dateutil.o
```

Create the shared lib:

```
gcc -shared dateutil.o mathutil.o -o bin/shared/libutil.so
```

Comment: Actually, I want to understand how to limit the binding of symbols of static library in shared library. Assuming there is a function func() in libmathutil.a with Global binding, when I link it in the shared library libutil.so, I want the binding of func() to be Local.

Comment: @Pendyala hmm..ok, then have you checked n.m.'s comment, where it looks like you are missing one of your static libs in your link command? try it like: `gcc -shared libutil.so -Wl,--whole-archive libmathutil.a libdateutil.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive`. This just keeps your whole archive block around the static libs only. Not sure if it really matters I have not tested that or read anything to suggest it does....